# How to get the name of the currently executing test in Canopy

Tags: selenium-webdriver, f#, canopy-web-testing

I would like to get the name of the currently executing canopy test inside the [`before`](https://lefthandedgoat.github.io/canopy/testing.html) function.

Is there some kind of global context I can refer to or do I need to dive into selenium?

Comment: It doesn't look like Canopy keeps a mutable context object that gets updated as tests run. If your test functions have names, you might be able to do something clever with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx to get the name of the current function, and print that. But that won't get you the description of the function, and the usual Canopy style is `"test description" &&& fun _ -> (test body)`. And that just creates an anonymous lambda function, which means StackTrace won't help.

Comment: Thought that might be the case!